# Why can't I create a 2D ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write the following code...

```
static ArrayList<RssItem>[][] list = new ArrayList<RssItem>[][];
```

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong, if I am trying to create a list of `ArrayList<RssItem>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the size on the RHS: -

```
static List<RssItem>[][] arr = (List<RssItem>[][])new List<?>[4][];
```

Size of `column` is not needed, but you can give it too: -

```
static List<RssItem>[][] arr = (List<RssItem>[][])new List<?>[4][5];
```

**NOTE**: -

You cannot give a `specific` type as a type parameter on the `RHS`. You would have to use `WildCard`. Specific type would only be given when you are instantiating your `list` in the array.

To add something to your array, you can use this kind of loop: -

**NOT Tested**

```
    List<RssItem>[][] arr = (List<RssItem>[][])new ArrayList<?>[4][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = new ArrayList<RssItem>();

            arr[i][j].add(new RssItem());
        }
    }

    for (List<RssItem>[] val: arr) {
       for (List<RssItem> val2: val) {
           System.out.println(val2);
       }
    }
```

**P.S.: -**

Please don't use 2-D array of `List`. That is equivalent to a 3-D array. Even if you get the above loop to work somehow. It will make your code mess in future. And your life hell. There are many other data structures in Java, that you should consider, like a `Map`, which is useful in such kind of situations.

Even, having a `List` upto 3 levels is a very bad idea. So, please change your design.

Comment: ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>(); I want to add rssItems in 2D array

Comment: @MaxUsanin. You created a 2-D array. Now you are iterating over the array using enhanced for-loop. In the outer loop,each element will be an array. And in the inner loop, each element will be a list. So, in the inner loop you have instantiated a list by using `new ArrayList<RssItem>();

Comment: this is understandable but it is do not understand (List<RssItem>[][])new ArrayList<?>  Well, okay - thanks anyway

Comment: @MaxUsanin Well, my question. What made you to use a 2-D array of an `ArrayList`. In fact that is a `3-D array`?? Why? Probably you should change the design. It is not a very good idea to have such a deeply nested array, specially when you have so many data structures in Java, that can ease up your work.

Comment: I use the ArrayList to display a list horoscopes, the difficulty is that there is a horoscope for the week for a month and a day
I have them stored in your array - this way I implement caching

Comment: You have separate horoscope for `week`, month and day? Then why can't you maintain 3 different list for that?

Comment: easier do so. Check out the loop I posted. How difficult it is to access 2 levels nested list. Your life would be much easier by using 3 lists.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create an array of a generic type. So You will need to use cast.

```
List<RssItem>[][] arr = (List<RssItem>[][]) new ArrayList<?>[2][2];
```

But still it will be good to implement List of List `ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>>`

```
List<ArrayList<RssItem>> list = new  ArrayList<ArrayList<RssItem>>();
arr[0][0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arr[0][0].add(10);
```

Comment: ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>(); I want to add rssItems in 2D array ...

Comment: @MaxUsanin Added example for that :)

Answer (score 0):

A generic array of Array lists = an array list of array lists

And that would be

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```